# facebook app, notify the user

Tags: facebook

I'm pretty new to facebook app. I want to make a simple app for learning. I want to create an app that visits mysite.com/page.json and prints some pretty html. Then i'd like to scan the json for 'private_message' and notify the user (and not publicly post on his/her wall) about the pm and print the message in their notification area.

The later is mostly what i want to learn. Where can i find the API reference? I looked at [fql/notification](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/notification) but it looks like its looking at the notifications when i want to post a notification.

Answer (score 0):

I think at the moment it's not possible to send a notification to a user unless it's an invitation to the application sent by another user.

What you can do instead is to use a Bookmark Counter - I guess that's the notification counterpart for the applications. Then the user can go to your application and read the message. More details here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#bookmarks